# NSAttributedString goes invisible on iOS 13 when build with Xcode 10.3

Tags: ios, ios13, xcode10.3

I'm seeing an issue with Xcode 10.3 and iOS 13. With this setup if I use NSAttributedString and set it to a UILabel, the text goes invisible. Same code will continue to work on lower iOS versions. If the same code is built/deployed using Xcode 11, iOS 13 renders the strings without any issue. Has anyone run in to this yet OR have potential solutions?

```
// attrlabel : UILabel
let attrStr = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: str, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.textEffect: NSAttributedString.TextEffectStyle.letterpressStyle])
            attrLabel.attributedText = attrStr
```

Comment: Try including a font and foreground color in the attributes.

Comment: I have checked with variety of attributes and all of them yields same result.

Comment: having the exact same problem...

Comment: I have the same strange issue with xcode 12.4

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
In my case I fixed it by not using .textEfect key, I use .attachment key instead